# Do people get saved from hell if one of their family member is in heaven?

Tags: mahabharata, sin, heaven, hell

Yudhistira was allocated heaven while other four Pandavs and Draupdi were allocated hell . But when Yudhistira requested Yamraj that he too would live in hell with his other four brothers and wife in hell, Yamraj reversed the situation and instead allocated heaven to other four brothers and Drapudi.
So, It seems like the four brothers and Draupdi were saved from hell due to Yudhistira.

Or Was it just a Maya to test Yudhistira and four Pandavs and Draupdi were never in hell ?

My question is -
If one person in a family did good deeds and other bad deeds, can the good guy of the family save the bad guys from hell ? Because if someone's family member is in hell , the person will not feel happy in heaven .(just like Yudhistira)

Comment: Pandavas case: Yudhistira was shown hell (Maya) because he lied to kill Drona... It is noted in Mahabharata.

Comment: The second part of question is linked to this:https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48217/do-karma-of-others-benefit-impact-us-atma